# Options for flying to Tokyo from Seoul

Tags: air-travel, japan, tokyo, south-korea, seoul

We are planning on the ferry from Fukuoka to Busan and then fly back to Tokyo from Seoul a week later. What are the options for flying one way from Seoul to Tokyo? We would like to find something cheap for a one way trip. I read somewhere that there is an option between the smaller airports of Seoul and Tokyo. Which airline?

Comment: When are you suppose to fly? What is your budget?

Comment: Mid April and as cheap as possible but still direct flight. Time is more important than cost.

Comment: I didn't realize this flight was so expensive. The cheapest I got was $322 by Delta which is a direct flight but I believe this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: thats the kind of prices I have found with some swift searches and thus the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an airline called [Eastar Jet](http://www.eastarjet.com) which offers flights from [Incheon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incheon_International_Airport), which is Seouls primary airport. There are `normal` and `discounted` fares, a normal one is 260,000KRW which is a bit over $230 and a discounted fare is 99,500KRW which comes to about $87. These fares are for flights to [Narita airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narita_International_Airport) in Tokyo for April 2012.

I got all the way through to the `Payment` page with a discounted fare which means a discounted fare applies to anyone (note that I didn't find out why discount is offered).

Hope this helps.

Comment: the site warns me for buying one way tickets. Should it be taken seriously?

Comment: I tried again and didn't get any warning. I would just have to click a Submit button and would probably process the payment. What kind of warning are you getting, what is it referring to?

Comment: It says I should get a return ticket - otherwise I may not be let on. Maybe it depends from where you are booking? I asked them on twitter but haven't got a reply yet.

Comment: Maybe they have policies for emigration similar to North Korea. Try sending an email to them, I don't know how likely it is that they'll respond via Twitter.

Comment: Having a ticket out of the country is a condition for entry for Japan, although in my experience this is enforced more by the airlines than Japanese immigration.  If you take the ferry in, then your flight ticket out is all you need; if you're going in the other direction, you might want to look into prebooking your ferry ticket.

Comment: so a return ticket from japan to sweden would do then! (also the airline cam back and said that it would be no problem)

Comment: only the next problem - only amex and diners accepted as payment...

Comment: Too bad, mate. I usually use Amex online so that would be a plus for me. I had the payment problem with Indian railways this year since it doesn't accept credit card payment from outside India neither do Croatian Visa debit cards have `Verified by Visa` certificate so I couldn't pay for the bookings myself. Well, good luck with the plane ticket...

Comment: managed to book now! pro tips: the site says only amex and diners but they [also accept visa and mastercard](https://twitter.com/?iid=am-136815635413297271726838680&nid=4+status_user&uid=693693&utm_content=profile#!/EastarJet_ZE/status/171514309241872384).